# JOLT Flatten array and nested object

Tags: java, json, apache-nifi, jolt

Given the following JSON

```json
{
  "id": "1234",
  "recordType": "E",
  "receiveDate": "2009-01-01",
  "receiveTime": "09:55:00",
  "releaseDate": "2009-01-02",
  "releaseTime": "08:30:00",
  "classifications": [
    {
      "reportType": 1031435,
      "description": {
        "string": "Progress Report"
      }
    },
    {
      "reportType": 1031435,
      "description": {
        "string": "Net Tangible Asset Backing"
      }
    }
  ],
  "type": "ASX"
}
```

I need to transform it to

```json
{
  "id": "1234",
  "recordType": "E",
  "classifications": [
    {
      "reportType": 1031435,
      "description": "Progress Report"
    },
    {
      "reportType": 1031435,
      "description": "Net Tangible Asset Backing"
    }
  ],
  "type": "ASX"
}
```

I'm having great difficulty trying to figure out exactly how to achieve this with Jolt or whether it's even possible at all.

Any help truly appreciated.
Ron Milne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "&",
      "recordT*": "&",
      "class*": {
        "*": {
          "reportT*": "&2[&1].&",
          "desc*": {
            "*": "&3[&2].&1"
          }
        }
      },
      "type": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

where **`*`** wilcards used to abbreviate the whole literals per each key names such as **`reportT*`** represents **`reportType`**, and single **`*`** wilcard represents the **others**(***else*** case)

Firstly we reached the innermost attributes( `"string":...` ) of the whole JSON value through use of `"*": {` following `"classifications"` key in order to walk through the indices of it. The `"&"` wildcard replicates each values for the corresponding attribute, `&3` and `&2` are used to replicate the array's name(`classifications`) by going 2 or 3 levels up and grabbing the literal per each, and `[&1]` or `[&2]` are used to determine the common factor for constructing the objects of the array.

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

**Edit** : If your aim is *to assign default values for missing array elements* as commented, then replace `"reportT*": "&2[&1].&"` with `"*": "&2[&1].&"` considering the case that the array `classifications` has more elements than the current state.

Comment: Thanks greatly appreciated, now how to assign default values for missing array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Saw your last comment that you want have default values for missing array elements.
You may consider another library *Josson* for the solution.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"id\": \"1234\"," +
    "  \"recordType\": \"E\"," +
    "  \"receiveDate\": \"2009-01-01\"," +
    "  \"receiveTime\": \"09:55:00\"," +
    "  \"releaseDate\": \"2009-01-02\"," +
    "  \"releaseTime\": \"08:30:00\"," +
    "  \"classifications\": [" +
    "    {" +
    "      \"reportType\": 1031435," +
    "      \"description\": {" +
    "        \"string\": \"Progress Report\"" +
    "      }" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "      \"reportType\": 8888888," +
    "      \"description\": {" +
    "        \"string\": \"Net Tangible Asset Backing\"" +
    "      }" +
    "    }" +
    "  ]," +
    "  \"type\": \"ASX\"" +
    "}");
```

Transformation

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "map(id," +
    "    recordType," +
    "    classifications" +
    "     .map(reportType, description:description.string)" +
    "     .wrap()" +
    "     .collect([0]," +
    "              ifNot([reportType=8888888], json('{\"reportType\":8888888,\"description\":\"Default item\"}'))," +
    "              ifNot([reportType=9999999], json('{\"reportType\":9999999,\"description\":\"Default item\"}')))" +
    "     .flatten(1)," +
    "    type)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "id" : "1234",
  "recordType" : "E",
  "classifications" : [ {
    "reportType" : 1031435,
    "description" : "Progress Report"
  }, {
    "reportType" : 8888888,
    "description" : "Net Tangible Asset Backing"
  }, {
    "reportType" : 9999999,
    "description" : "Default item"
  } ],
  "type" : "ASX"
}
```